# What is the fastest way to print out to a terminal?

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

The question is pretty straight-forward, what is the fastest way to print out a string to the terminal?

I am making an "ASCII graphics engine" in C++, particularly on Linux, and i have noticed that printing with some big resolutions can be pretty slow.

Now, of course, its pretty fast, but still.

I want to find out whats the absolute fastest. Some things i have tried are just printing with `cout`, then i realized that was slow.

Then i printed with `printf` which was a huge difference.

I tried getting something faster by just using `fwrite` with stdout, but it didnt really make any noticeable difference.

I know it also depends on the terminal emulator, but im looking for whats the fastest way to do it in code.

I have noticed that Windows terminals are pretty fast, you can just directly write to the terminal buffer with the terminals, instead of printing to `stdout`.

Is there anything similiar to this on Linux?

Comment: Half joking, but to be really fast use 3D acceleration (opengl). Setup a mesh (of squares), assign textures of those squares based on content of the terminal (e.g. a 80 by 25 buffer). 
But that might be more then you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, but the trick here is to not use any graphical libraries for this project.

Comment: Have you made sure you're using `sync_with_stdio()` correctly on `std::cout`?

Have you made sure you've put the terminal driver in raw mode?

Comment: ? Elaborate on "terminal driver". Do you mean just using `ioctl` to put the terminal in raw mode? I haven't tried that, but is there a more cross platform solution?

Comment: I have tested raw mode (with termios), it didnt help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Hey This might help you

you can use `echo ""` to print this is the fastest way to print on terminal

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yeah but, you cant really do it in C++, `system()` is probably slower than normal printing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `echo “text”` is the fastest way. The other fastest method is `std::cout`, it’s much faster than `printf` because it doesn’t parse text at runtime. `cout` is slower because it syncs to `stdio`, add `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` to your main function to make `cout` faster

Comment: Small issue: that disables ANSI escape sequences, which i need for moving the cursor for example.